# beutifulsoup python error when i am importing the package

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I get below error when i try to import beautifulsoup. I am using enthough canopy and the package manager shows me that beautifulsoup4 4.4.1-3 is installed. What is going on and how could i fix it?

```
----> 6 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
      7 
      8 #This is the url that will be queried. You can change this to something else

ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

See the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).